# Woocommerce - how to match orders and items back to customers

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've been provided with a Woocommerce SQL dump (don't have access to that platform anymore as it was shut down), and need to identify their most valuable customers and what they bought, i.e. 
Customer X spent the most at $X, and the last purchase item was 'Red umbrella'
Customer Y spent next most at $Y etc

I can see a wp_users table which has the customer data, a wp_woocommerce_order_items table which has the items data.

My question is - where can I find revenue data, and how can I link these tables (which IDs in each table correspond to which other ID in other tables?) - in particular how do I link customers, to orders, to items?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the table wp_postmeta in that table, the field _customer_user will hold the id of the customer who placed that order post_id field in that same table.

Comment: Thanks. In this table I see rows which have the value '_customer_user' in the 'meta_key' column - is this what you mean? If so, the other columns are 'meta_id' and 'post_id' - so the post_id is the order ID and the meta_id is the customer ID, is that right? Seems a bit strange since if you use this logic each customer here only has 1 order which is unlikely for this company.

Comment: Each "post_id" (This will be the ID of Order) having same value for "_customer_user" represents a different order of that user. Look for that and you can find all orders of that specific user.